# chdir syscall in os x assembler

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64

I am trying to make sure I am using syscalls correctly in OS X assembly language. I am using NASM and the sample below is the shortest program I can create that reproduces the problem:

```
1 section .data
2 path        db      "/Users/querist",0x00
3 section .text
4 global start
5 
6 start:
7 mov rax, 0x0200000b     ; System call chdir = 12
8 mov rdi, path           ; address of path string
9 sub rsp, 16             ; add space to stack for local variables
10 syscall                 ; Invoke the kernel
11 mov rdi, rax            ; save return code from previous function
12 mov rax, 0x02000001     ; System call number for exit = 1
13 syscall                 ; Invoke the kernel
```

I know that the change of directory only applies to the process for the program itself so it will not change my working directory in the command shell I am using. I was actually trying to create a directory as a test but the chdir call fails with an error code of 78, which indicates a "configuration error".

The target directory exists and it is my user directory, so I have permission to go to it. I receive the same error code if I try to use a relative path (such as "..") instead.

I can create a directory using a syscall using either a relative or absolute path, but the chdir call does not work.

Also, how can I get a string with the current path name without linking the c libraries?

thanks

Comment: `add rsp, 16` is not allocating space at all. Maybe you meant `sub rsp, 16` but even that seems unnecessary here, you don't use any locals? I am surprised that even links, other people usually report that OSX doesn't allow absolute references. Are you sure you actually run this code? If it magically links and runs, chances are it's still using the wrong address. I would try to use the OSX equivalent of `strace` to see the arguments. As a guess, I would do `lea rdi, [rel path]` instead of `mov rdi, path`.

Comment: Boy do I feel foolish. Yes, that should be sub rsp, 16. According to the documentation I read on syscalls in OS X, you need to do that before the syscall to allocate some space. It seemed odd to me because the syscalled function itself could just allocate the space.

Fixed the code, same error.

Comment: Should not line 7 use 0x0200000c?

Comment: ::hangs head in shame:: Yes, it should be 0x0200000c. I've been sick for the past three days.

Comment: `0xb` is decimal 11, not decimal 12.

Comment: This is what I get for trying to code while I'm overly sick. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in this case it was truly just a matter of typos and being too sick to see what was going on. I feel sufficiently embarrassed now.

Corrected, working code:

```
1 section .data
2 path        db      "/Users/querist",0x00,0x00
3 section .text
4 global start
5 
6 start:
7 mov rax, 0x0200000c     ; System call chdir = 12
8 lea rdi, [rel path]           ; address of path string
9 sub rsp, 16             ; add space to stack for local variables
10 syscall                 ; Invoke the kernel
11 mov rdi, rax            ; save return code from previous function
12 mov rax, 0x02000001     ; System call number for exit = 1
13 syscall                 ; Invoke the kernel
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you need to reserve space on the user stack before running `syscall`?  Surely OS X doesn't use the user-space stack for anything?  The kernel can't trust it, because another use-space thread could be modifying it while `syscall` runs, in an attempt to exploit the kernel.  It's also not far enough to preserve the red zone, which would be necessary in general if OS X's `syscall` handler wrote to the user stack.  `syscall` switches to kernel mode, but doesn't modify `rsp`.  Linux saves the integer registers in the task struct for that process, IIRC.

Comment: Also note that some assemblers (e.g. yasm) won't optimize `mov rax, 32bit-constant` down to `mov eax, imm32`, but will emit `REX mov r64, sign-extended-imm32`

Comment: https://filippo.io/making-system-calls-from-assembly-in-mac-os-x/ doesn't say anything about having to `sub rsp, 16` before a syscall, and has a "hello world" example.

Comment: I agree - the sub rsp, 16 didn't make sense to me either - I was actually trying to eliminate _any_ variables by doing stuff exactly as I saw on the other sites. I first learned assembly language back in the 1980s on an old DEC PDP-8e, then the 6502/6510 chips, and then the Motorola 680x0 series chips. I'm still catching up on x86.

Thanks for catching that. I've been sick and I feel silly now for missing such obvious errors in the code.

Comment: I initially learned m68k asm.  One of the first programs I ever did anything with was a Mandelbrot program in C for the Atari ST (similar to amiga), I typed in from a magazine article.  I had an STe with a 16MHz 68000 and 4MiB of RAM and a hard drive, but `gcc` still took a long time to compile.  So while tweaking it to run faster, I started editing the asm :P  I think I eventually had it writing directly to video RAM or something.  IDK why everyone thinks x86 is hard to learn.  It's actually *easier* than RISC in some ways, because you can just use large immediate operands.

Comment: Anyway, the examples you were trying to exactly copy almost certainly popped the stack (`add rsp, 16`) at some point after the system call.  You don't need to because your next syscall is `exit`, which doesn't return.